# How to draw svg line graph containing Bezier curve functionality in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am collecting incoming data from user with x and y coordinates and some score point in addition . Now I want to display that data in svg line . Data from user contain all positive and negative values . So I want to plot line in coordinate plane like line can be in any shape .
for eg - as we move cursor on screen draw svg curved line.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Reachart library -Recharts is a Redefined chart library built with React and D3.

The main purpose of this library is to help you to write charts in React applications without any pain. Main principles of Recharts are:

1. Simply deploy with React components.
2. Native SVG support, lightweight depending only on some D3
   submodules.
3. Declarative components, components of charts are purely
   presentational.
4. Highly customizable
   **ref link - https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/JointLineScatterChart**

Answer (score 0):

**You could use functionality from d3.js.
https://d3js.org/**

### Line generator

It makes it possible to provide an array of x,y coordinates and generate a valid svg path from it, that can be then be used for visualisation.

https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v3.1.0/README.md#lines

**Example**: https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-line
It also provides options for interpolations, like Bezier

### Path Generator

If you need more control over your visualisation, you could use the path generator.

https://github.com/d3/d3-path/blob/v3.0.1/README.md#path

Example: https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-path

Comment: I will definitely try this library but any suggestions for implementing it from scratch like i want to draw the the same using svg or canvas

Comment: Please see the referenced examples in my post.